# Does OpenAPI 3 allow duplicate parameter names but in different locations (path/query/header)?

Tags: openapi

I am not sure if I understand the specification correctly. For example, [this](http://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3#parameter-object) states that a unique parameter is defined by a combination of its *name* and *location*.

Does that mean I can have a path parameter called "hello", a query parameter called "hello", and a header called "hello" all at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean I can have a path parameter called "hello", a query parameter called "hello", and a header called "hello" all at the same time?

Yes - because path/query/header parameters go into different parts of an HTTP request.

```
GET /path/hello/subpath?hello=value  <-- path and query
Host: example.com
hello: 123                           <-- HTTP header
```